# Instructions to run CherryPy behind Apache under Ubuntu

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cherrypy, mod-proxy, static-files

I'm planing to run my web server using CherryPy behind Apache. The idea is to let Apache handle the static files while CherryPy handles the web apps. After searching here and there I feel persuaded to use either mod_rewrite or mod_proxy as interface between Apache and CherryPy. I don't know the advantages and/or disadvantages of these two. I could use mod_rewrite or mod_proxy depending on which one is easier to configure or use. I believe there are not major functional differences between the two interfaces when used for this purpose. But, of course, I could be wrong.

I need explicit instructions on how to configure Apache under Ubuntu for this purpose. I have full control of this computer and the server hosts only one domain. Here are some details.

In the computer the static files are located at `/var/www/`
In the computer the web apps will be located at `/var/app/`
The URL for the web apps is supposed to be `http://www.example.com/app/`
CherryPy could use any port I want.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As for mod_rewrite or mod_proxy, perhaps see [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/144643/apache-mod-proxy-vs-mod-rewrite) on serverfault.  Personally, I use mod_rewrite.  Really, for such a simple setup you really just need a simple RewriteRule to proxy to your CP app, something like: `RewriteRule ^app/?(.*)             http://127.0.0.1:33333/$1 [proxy]`  The rest of your Apache config (static files) is as normal.

Comment: @Felix, Thanks for your reply. After you fixed my previous issue with withCherryPy serving static files, I'm no longer in urgent need for the Apache/CherryPy combo. However, it is a good idea to know how to make Apache and CherryPy play nice to each other. So this is good stuff for everybody anyway.

Comment: To be frank, you really ought to let Apache handle your static files. There's really no good argument in favor of letting CherryPy handle the static files, esp. if you'll already be running Apache/nginx etc.  Let Apache do what it does best (serve up static goods) and CherryPy do what it does best (serve up the dynamic content from your app).

Comment: @Felix, I will give it a try. My rationale was to keep thing simple: using one tool instead of two. So far I like CherryPy a lot. With it you don't spend a lot of time fighting the app<->browser interface. I simply wish Python was available on the client side instead of JavaScript, but that is a whole subject on its own.